# How to add Side nav toggle icon when side nav gets open in angular material

Tags: angular-material

[image]How to display sidenav toggle icon when the sidenav open the side nav toggle icon displays only the screen is small. Currently side nav gets opened,  when I close the sidenav the side nav toggle icon disappears screen of medium width.

I have added icon but it is not working

```
<mat-sidenav-container class="sidenav-container">
  <mat-sidenav #drawer class="sidenav" fixedInViewport
      [attr.role]="(isHandset$ | async) ? 'dialog' : 'navigation'"
      [mode]="(isHandset$ | async) ? 'over' : 'side'"
      [opened]="(isHandset$ | async) === false">
    <mat-toolbar>
        <button mat-icon-button  (click)="drawer.toggle()" >
            <mat-icon>menu</mat-icon>
          </button>
    </mat-toolbar>
    <mat-nav-list>
      <a mat-list-item href="#">DashBoard</a>
      <a mat-list-item href="#">Ports</a>
      <a mat-list-item href="#">Berth</a>
    </mat-nav-list>
  </mat-sidenav>
  <mat-sidenav-content>
    <mat-toolbar color="primary">
      <button
        type="button"
        aria-label="Toggle sidenav"
        mat-icon-button
        (click)="drawer.toggle()"
        *ngIf="isHandset$ | async"
        >
        <mat-icon aria-label="Side nav toggle icon">menu</mat-icon>
      </button>
      <span>ESAAR</span>
    </mat-toolbar>
   <app-vessel-details></app-vessel-details>
  </mat-sidenav-content>
</mat-sidenav-container>
```

Side nav should be opened for the screen of medium width.